# Error bar in python plot

Tags: python, plot

[image]

HI! I have this code in python

```
plt.errorbar(W50DM,VmaxDM,W50DM_std, fmt='r^')
plt.semilogy()
plt.semilogx()
plt.axis([10, 1000, 1, 1000])
plt.xlabel("VmaxDM")
plt.ylabel("W50DM")
plt.show()
```

W50DM_std contains the standard deviations for W50DM. The problems is that the elements of W50DM_std are all bigger than 0, usually bigger than 10, but as you can see in the plot there are some points with no standard deviation. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Identify these particular items by reducing the number of elements in your data, by subsequently removing most of them, until you're left with the single datum that causes the problem. Then update the question. Otherwise it is hard to guess what is the issue here.

Comment: Try to reduce this to a minimal working example, and show us what the data looks like so we can try to reproduce this behavior.